# Isolated Function App not responding to HTTP calls

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I have previously used in-process function apps without any issue.

I start them with `func host start`, and then I can invoke any REST endpoints locally using cURL.

To keep up with later dotnet versions, I've decided to give the isolated runtime a try.

I've setup a very simple project that only exposes a single endpoint, as outlined in the [documentation for the http trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

```cs
public class RestEndpoints
{
    private readonly ILogger<RestEndpoints> _logger;

    public RestEndpoints(ILogger<RestEndpoints> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(nameof(Run))]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("message logged");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.WriteString("Welcome to .NET isolated worker !!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs` I have the baseline setup. From what I've read I can't see anything additional is needed for this scenario:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

I start this application the same way as I did in-process with `func host start`. It starts alright and lists my endpoint as:

> Run: [GET] http://localhost:7071/api/Run

However, when I try to invoke this using cURL, the call just hangs. I can see log output that the runtime was reached, but I cannot get a response from the endpoint:

> [2023-08-22T09:48:28.362Z] Executing 'Functions.Run' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=98b63dcc-dce5-4b9d-bee8-dee1ea98a653)

In my csproj file I have the following dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.8.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
```

I am using Azure Function Core Tools `4.46.0`.

What am I missing here?

**Trying debug mode**

As pointed out to me, I tried debug mode as well but I get the same result:

```
func host start --pause-on-error --dotnet-isolated-debug --enable-json-output

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5274 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.23.0.20886

[2023-08-22T11:34:02.028Z] Found MyProject.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2023-08-22T11:34:04.234Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 70640) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...

Functions:

    Run: [GET] http://localhost:7071/api/Run

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-08-22T11:34:09.120Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000C146DC40'.
[2023-08-22T11:34:10.565Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2023-08-22T11:35:12.462Z] Executing 'Functions.Run' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=2a8207da-dc97-447e-b9de-60facda8481c)
```

The last line in the above output is from me using cURL to try and invoke the endpoint, then nothing else happens.

Comment: Did you try to start it in debug mode with debugger attached? Stepping through the endpoint might enlighten you.

Comment: I've tried both `func host start` and `func host start --dotnet-isolated-debug` now and it yields the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by updating your `.csproj` dependencies with the following values:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
```

You could also attempt to change your output type to `ASP.NET Core` types as per [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration-preview)

Comment: You are angel, it seems like this was the issue. All I did was bump `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` to `1.19.0` and `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` to `1.13.1`. Both of these seem to be the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

*I have reproduced the issue at my environment and after executing the function in debug mode, it worked for me*

Thanks @Fildor for pointing it out, Even I was also getting the same issue, when I directly tried to start the function using `func host start` command but then I ran the function like below

[image]

*I got the expected result-*

[image]

Try running the function in debug mode after creation.

Comment: Thank you for your time trying to reproduce this. Unfortunately I still run into the same issue (update my question with the information), which makes me think the issue is with my environment.

Comment: can you create the same function in Visual studio and see if you are still getting the error. Because when I try first time in Visual Studio, It worked

Comment: I am using Rider, I tried both the Rider managed function core tools and the one I've installed using brew. I think vscode just uses the installed version, which I guess would yield the same result.